# JavaScript Graph remove vertex

Tags: javascript, graph

I'm implementing my own Graph class in JavaScript. I have add vertex, add edge, and remove edge methods working just fine. I'm trying to create the remove vertex method, but it is not removing all edges of a vertex.

My Class:

```
class Graph {
    constructor() {
        this.graph = new Map();
    }

    addVertex(name) {
        if(!this.graph.has(name))
            this.graph.set(name, []);
        return;
    }

    addEdge(node1, node2) {
        this.addVertex(node1);
        this.addVertex(node2);
        const data1 = this.graph.get(node1);
        const data2 = this.graph.get(node2);
        data1.push(node2);
        data2.push(node1);
        this.graph.set(node1, data1);
        this.graph.set(node2, data2);
        return;
    }

    removeEdge(node1, node2) {
        if(this.graph.has(node1)) {
            const data1 = this.graph.get(node1);
            for(let i=0; i<data1.length; i++) {
                if(data1[i] === node2) {
                    data1.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
                this.graph.set(node1, data1);
            } 
        }

        if(this.graph.has(node2)) {
            const data2 = this.graph.get(node2);
            for(let i=0; i<data2.length; i++) {
                if(data2[i] === node1) {
                    data2.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
                this.graph.set(node2, data2);
            } 
        }
    }

    removeVertex(node1) {
        if(!this.graph.has(node1))  return;

        const data = this.graph.get(node1);
        for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            this.removeEdge(data[i], node1);
        }
        this.graph.delete(node1);
        return;
    }
}
```

My test data:

```
    let graph = new Graph();
    graph.addVertex('A');
    graph.addVertex('B');
    graph.addVertex('A');
    graph.addEdge('A', 'B');
    graph.addEdge('A', 'C');
    graph.addEdge('C', 'D');
    graph.addEdge('A', 'D');
    graph.addEdge('B', 'C');
    //graph.removeEdge('A', 'B');
    graph.removeVertex('D');
        console.log(graph);
```

The output is:

```
Graph {
  graph: Map {
    'A' => [ 'B', 'C', 'D' ],
    'B' => [ 'A', 'C' ],
    'C' => [ 'A', 'B' ]
  }
}
```

It deleted the vertex 'D' and the edge D-C, but it did not deleted the edge A-D. It is very odd, but it looks like it is running just the first loop of the for-loop below.

```
for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
   this.removeEdge(data[i], node1);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The problem is using `splice` inside a loop over the very same array (`data`).

Comment: Those `this.graph.set(node, data);` don't make sense. They're inside a loop, for one, and they are no-ops as exactly that data is already stored in the map. Notice that arrays are mutable objects, nothing in your code creates a copy of them.

Comment: @Bergi Could you give me an example of how I could fix it?

Comment: Use directed edges and remove the code duplication from `addEdge` and `removeEdge` (if you want undirected edges, add wrapping methods like `addEdges(a, b) { this.addEdge(a, b); this.addEdge(b, a); }`). This will allow you to call `removeEdge` in `removeVertex` with only the back edges, then swooping the forward egdes in one go with the `this.graph.delete(node)`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could a) clone the array before iterating over it so that you are not affected by the (inefficient) splices or b) use an inner `Set` instead of an array so that you can delete by value instead of by index.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem as well and it took me some time to figure this one out. This problem arises due to the combination of the use of splice in the `removeEdge` method, which changes the `data` array and using `i<data.length` in the for loop. Since, the length of the `data` array is changing (because its elements are being deleted in the `removeEdge` method), you cannot use `i<data.length` as it will not iterate through all the elements in the `data` array.

Here is a dry run of the `removeVertex` method.

Initially, we have `"D" => ["C", "A"]`.

Now, in the `removeVertex` method, `data = ["C", "A"]` and `data.length = 2`.
As we start the loop, `i=0`, 0 < 2 (`i<data.length`) and `data[i] = data[0] = "C"`, so the vertices "C" and "D" are passed to the `removeEdge` method.

In the `removeEdge` method, we get `data2 = ["C", "A"]`, which is the same as `data` array in the `removeVertex` method. Then the splice method deletes "C" as we remove the edge C-D. This lefts `data2 = ["A"]`, which means that the array associated with the key "D" has changed to ["A"], which further means that the array `data` in the `removeVertex` method is now also `["A"]`.

Now, we return back to the `removeVertex` method, where `i=1`, `data = ["A"]` and the condition `i<data.length` fails (because 1 is not greater than 1). This means that the loop is over and the edge A-D not removed, which is why "D" shows up in the array associated with key "A" and "A" shows up in the array associated with "D" ("D" => ["A"]).

Note - You don't get "D" => ["A"] in the output, because the last line of your
`removeVertex` function explicitly deletes the array associated with the key "D".

To rectify the problem, first store the length of the `data` array and then use a while loop. The advantage of using a while loop is very subtle, because we start looping the `data` array from the end and then its elements are deleted in the `removeEdge` method, which has no effect on the while loop. Here it is -

```js
removeVertex(node1) {
    if(!this.graph.has(node1))  return;

    const data = this.graph.get(node1);
    let len = data.length;
    while(len) {
        this.removeEdge(data[i], node1);
        len--;
    }
    this.graph.delete(node1);
    return;
}
```

Hope it helps!